# mongodb get distinct records

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-scala

I am using `mongoDB` in which I have collection of following format.

```
{"id" : 1 , name : x  ttm : 23 , val : 5 }
{"id" : 1 , name : x  ttm : 34 , val : 1 }
{"id" : 1 , name : x  ttm : 24 , val : 2 }
{"id" : 2 , name : x  ttm : 56 , val : 3 }
{"id" : 2 , name : x  ttm : 76 , val : 3 }
{"id" : 3 , name : x  ttm : 54 , val : 7 }
```

On that collection I have queried to get records in descending order like this:

```
db.foo.find({"id" : {"$in" : [1,2,3]}}).sort(ttm : -1).limit(3)
```

But it gives two records of same `id = 1` and I want records such that it gives 1 record per `id`.

Is it possible in mongodb?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is a `distinct` command in mongodb, that can be used in conjunction with a query. However, I believe this just returns a distinct list of values for a specific key you name (i.e. in your case, you'd only get the id values returned) so I'm not sure this will give you exactly what you want if you need the whole documents - you may require MapReduce instead.

Documentation on distinct:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Distinct

Comment: Thanks ,yes, I want whole documents but no duplicate id document

Comment: `distinct(:id)` returns whole documents without duplicated id.

Comment: @Voldy - I can't get that syntax to work in the mongo shell, gives me a syntax error?

Comment: @AdaTheDev I use it with `mongoid` in Rails. For example, this returns all categories which have products `Category.all(:id => Deal.distinct(:category_id))`. I think it somehow translates to mongo syntax..

Comment: @Voldy - ah OK thanks, I'd be interested to find out what that translates to - I use the CSharp driver. Will try and dig about a bit more

Comment: @Voldy - actually on second look, what I think it's doing is the distinct part of that will just be returning a list of category ids from Deal, which are then passed back in to a query against Category. i.e. the "distinct" part of that (per the docs) I imagine is in fact only returning the single field.

Answer (score 25):

You want to use aggregation. You could do that like this:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    // each Object is an aggregation.
    {
        $group: {
            originalId: {$first: '$_id'}, // Hold onto original ID.
            _id: '$id', // Set the unique identifier
            val:  {$first: '$val'},
            name: {$first: '$name'},
            ttm:  {$first: '$ttm'}
        }

    }, {
        // this receives the output from the first aggregation.
        // So the (originally) non-unique 'id' field is now
        // present as the _id field. We want to rename it.
        $project:{
            _id : '$originalId', // Restore original ID.

            id  : '$_id', // 
            val : '$val',
            name: '$name',
            ttm : '$ttm'
        }
    }
])
```

This will be *very* fast... ~90ms for my test DB of 100,000 documents.

Example:

```js
db.test.find()
// { "_id" : ObjectId("55fb595b241fee91ac4cd881"), "id" : 1, "name" : "x", "ttm" : 23, "val" : 5 }
// { "_id" : ObjectId("55fb596d241fee91ac4cd882"), "id" : 1, "name" : "x", "ttm" : 34, "val" : 1 }
// { "_id" : ObjectId("55fb59c8241fee91ac4cd883"), "id" : 1, "name" : "x", "ttm" : 24, "val" : 2 }
// { "_id" : ObjectId("55fb59d9241fee91ac4cd884"), "id" : 2, "name" : "x", "ttm" : 56, "val" : 3 }
// { "_id" : ObjectId("55fb59e7241fee91ac4cd885"), "id" : 2, "name" : "x", "ttm" : 76, "val" : 3 }
// { "_id" : ObjectId("55fb59f9241fee91ac4cd886"), "id" : 3, "name" : "x", "ttm" : 54, "val" : 7 }


db.test.aggregate(/* from first code snippet */)

// output
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("55fb59f9241fee91ac4cd886"),
            "val" : 7,
            "name" : "x",
            "ttm" : 54,
            "id" : 3
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("55fb59d9241fee91ac4cd884"),
            "val" : 3,
            "name" : "x",
            "ttm" : 56,
            "id" : 2
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("55fb595b241fee91ac4cd881"),
            "val" : 5,
            "name" : "x",
            "ttm" : 23,
            "id" : 1
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

PROS: Almost certainly the fastest method.

CONS: Involves use of the complicated Aggregation API. Also, it is tightly coupled to the original schema of the document. Though, it may be possible to generalize this.

Answer (score 9):

I believe you can use aggregate like this

```
collection.aggregate({
   $group : {
        "_id" : "$id",
        "docs" : { 
            $first : { 
            "name" : "$name",
            "ttm" : "$ttm",
            "val" : "$val",
            }
        } 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

The issue is that you want to distill 3 matching records down to one without providing any logic in the query for how to choose between the matching results.

Your options are basically to specify aggregation logic of some kind (select the max or min value for each column, for example), or to run a select distinct query and only select the fields that you wish to be distinct.

[querymongo.com](http://www.querymongo.com) does a good job of translating these distinct queries for you (from SQL to MongoDB).

For example, this SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT columnA FROM collection WHERE columnA > 5
```

Is returned as this MongoDB:

```
db.runCommand({
    "distinct": "collection",
    "query": {
        "columnA": {
            "$gt": 5
        }
    },
    "key": "columnA"
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to write the distinct result in a file using javascript...this is how you do

```
cursor = db.myColl.find({'fieldName':'fieldValue'})

var Arr = new Array();
var count = 0;

cursor.forEach(

function(x) {

    var temp = x.id;    
var index = Arr.indexOf(temp);      
if(index==-1)
   {
     printjson(x.id);
     Arr[count] = temp;
         count++;
   }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Specify Query with distinct.
The following example returns the distinct values for the field sku, embedded in the item field, from the documents whose dept is equal to "A":

```
db.inventory.distinct( "item.sku", { dept: "A" } )
```

Reference: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/