# mongoDB distinct & where in same query?

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I have the following documents

```
Article { Comment: embedMany }

Comment { Reply: embedMany }

Reply { email: string, ip: string }
```

I want to make a query that selects distinct `Reply.ip` where `Reply.email = xxx`

Something like this, only it doesn't work..

```
db.Article.find("Comment.Reply.email" : "xxx").distinct("Comment.Reply.ip")
```

---

**JSON export:**

```
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"4e71be36c6eed629c61cea2c"
   },
   "name":"test",
   "Comment":[
      {
         "name":"comment test",
         "Reply":[
            {
               "ip":"192.168.2.1",
               "email":"yyy"
            },
            {
               "ip":"127.0.0.1",
               "email":"zzz"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"comment 2 test",
         "Reply":[
            {
               "ip":"128.168.1.1",
               "email":"xxx"
            },
            {
               "ip":"192.168.1.1",
               "email":"xxx"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

**I run** : `db.Article.distinct("Comment.Reply.ip",{"Comment.Reply.email" : "xxx"})`

**I expect** : `["128.168.1.1", "192.168.1.1"]`

**I get** : `["127.0.0.1", "128.168.1.1", "192.168.1.1", "192.168.2.1"]`

Comment: Have my upvote for the "I run", "I expect", "I get", if only all questions where formatted like this!

Comment: Here's a variant of the solution
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13864518/358013

Answer (score 108, accepted):

`Distinct` query in mongo with condition works like this

```
 db.Article.distinct("Comment.Reply.ip",{"Comment.Reply.email" : "xxx"})
```

not other way around

**EDIT:**

I understand the problem now, inorder to match/filter subdocuments we need to use $elemMatch operator, like this

```
  db.Article.distinct("Comment.Reply.ip",{Comment: {$elemMatch: {"Reply.email" : "xxx"}}})
```

but this will not work if the sub-document  contains sub arrays (in your case, you have array of replies). There is an existing issue [$elemMatch on subArray](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1264) is opened. And its planned for mongo 2.1. You can check out the link for more info

Comment: I tried it and it seems to ignore condition, so results is the same as db.Article.distinct("Comment.Reply.ip")

Comment: @Inori, above code works perfectly fine in my environment... can you post your actual data and the result you got so i can dig in...

Comment: Guess I have to wait for 2.1 :/ Thanks for the reply anyways!

Answer (score 5):

`db.collection.distinct("field_name", query)`

will return all the distinct values from your collection in the form of an array

**field_name** should be the field for which you want to return distinct values.

**query** specifies the documents from where you want to retrieve the distinct values. ex :- `{"Comment.Reply.email" : "xxx"}` or `{'country' : 'India','state' : 'MH','city' : 'mumbai'}`

Comment: This one is really good. I was trying to write aggregation query for this.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could try this

```
db.Article.aggregate([
{$unwind: "$Comment"},
{$unwind: "$Comment.Reply"},
{$match: {"Comment.Reply.email": "xxx"}},
{$group: {_id: "$Comment.Reply.ip"}}
])
```

The result of example should be

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "192.168.1.1"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "128.168.1.1"
}
```

Answer (score -6):

```
distinctdates=db.dailyreport_detailed.find(

{'uid':personemail,'month':searchdate2,'year':searchdate1}
)

.distinct('date_only')
```

where find will retrieve as per condition and distinct at the end will give unique dates.

Comment: This does not work. It returns: 'distinct is not a function'