# mongo select all unique combinations of document attributes

Tags: python, mongodb

If I had a collection of documents like the following:

```
{a:'1', b:'2', c:'3', d:'a'},
{a:'1', b:'2', c:'1', d:'b'},
{a:'1', b:'2', c:'3', d:'c'},
{a:'1', b:'3', c:'1', d:'d'},
{a:'1', b:'2', c:'3', d:'e'},
{a:'2', b:'2', c:'1', d:'f'}
```

What would be the most efficient mongo query to get all the unique combinations of the attributes a, b, c? Is it possible? The result looking something like:

```
{a:'1', b:'2', c:'3', d:*},
{a:'1', b:'2', c:'1', d:*},
{a:'1', b:'3', c:'1', d:*},
{a:'2', b:'2', c:'1', d:*}
```

`*` = don't care

Thanks, your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The usual tool for this kind of operation is the `distinct` function. Unfortunately, MongoDB's `distinct` can only filter on one field (e.g. `db.collection.distinct("a")`). Various work-around are possible, for example using `aggregate` or `group`.

**Example with [aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/group/):**

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $group: {
        _id: {
            a: "$a", 
            b: "$b", 
            c: "$c"
        }
    }
})
```

You will have to extract the information from the result, but I guess this is not a huge problem.

**Example with [group](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.group/):**

```
db.collection.group({
    key: {
        a: 1, 
        b: 1,
        c: 1
    }, 
    reduce: function (current, result) {}, 
    initial: {}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this

```
db.<your collection>.aggregate([{$group:{"a": "$a", "b": "$b", "c": "$c"}}])
```

also try this link [mongodb get distinct records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089162/mongodb-get-distinct-records)

I'm not MongoDB professional, but I think you also can use js function, like this:

```
a = {}
db.<your collection>.find().forEach(
    function(x)
    {
        if (a[[x.a, x.b, x.c]] == null) {
            a[[x.a, x.b, x.c]] = true;
            printjson(x);
        }
    }
)
```